# Impossible to get back data saved in SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
private RadioGroup rgTravel;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static final String PREFS = "PREFS";
private static final String Travel = "travel";
private RadioButton radioButton;
String travel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);


    final Button btnOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent activity3 = new Intent(MainActivity2Activity.this, MainActivity3Activity.class);


            rgTravel = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTravel);
            int selectedId = rgTravel.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            travel = radioButton.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences preferences-= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity2Activity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(Travel, travel);
            editor.commit();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), travel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(activity3);

        }

    });
}
```

**This is my activity2, where I'm supposed create the sharedpreference, and save the user's choice. (I want save the choice of the user in a radiogroup)
See my activity 3 where I'm supposed get back the choice :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String choice;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);

        SharedPreferences PREFS = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        choice = PREFS.getString("Travel", "Beach");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), choice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        displayPicture(choice);


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent activity4 = new Intent(MainActivity3Activity.this, MainActivity4Activity.class);
                startActivity(activity4);
            }
        });
    }
```

**I have created a Toast in each activity in order to be sure that the problem is really with the preference and not with another step.**

Comment: You should mark Pavneet_Singh's answer as correct.It is the check mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `travel` not `Travel` because it is case sensitive

Use in next activity

```
choice = PREFS.getString("travel", "Beach");
```

instead of

```
choice = PREFS.getString("Travel", "Beach");
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding